# What does the citation YEAR Misc NN mean?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-citation

The case Bower v Brewdog bears at the top of its bailii page a citation, [2019] EW Misc. 16 (CC), which I would like to break down to. understand.

I assume that CC is an abbreviation for County Court (ie denoting the levlel of the court as would be done by EWHC or EWCA or UKHL or UKSC etc).

2019 is clearly the year.

Is 16 a serial number? What series does it refer to, if so?

And what does Misc. indicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

County Courts do not have official neutral citations and are placed in the Miscellaneous category by the British and Irish Legal Information Institute, who nowadays acts as the unofficial case reporter in the UK. See https://www.bailii.org/bailii/citation.html for a list of courts whose proceedings have official neutral citations.

The series number appears to be decided by BAILII, probably based on the time it publishes a case.